# Stacked bars not showing up with unique sets of data

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to show `different countries and its citywise population` using `stacked bar chart` but the data set being `unique` with the cities and countries being uniquely exclusive to each other my chart is showing up only the first data in the set as per the code. But how to make it work so that it could show all the data in with different stacked bars for each country. Here is the code for what I have tried so far : https://jsbin.com/qopazukahi/edit?html,output.

Below is my dataset:

```
var data=[
  {
    "Country": "India",
    "Delhi": 310504,
    "Kolkata": 552339,
    "Chennai": 259034,
  },
  {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "Melbourne": 62083,
    "Sydney": 85640,
    "Perth": 42153,
    "Canberra": 74257,
    },
  {
    "Country": "USA",
    "New York": 415910,
    "Miami": 828669,
    "Frankfort": 362642,
    "Portland": 601943,
    "Topeka": 1804762,
  },

];
```

Here is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var data=[
  {
    "Country": "India",
    "Delhi": 310504,
    "Kolkata": 552339,
    "Chennai": 259034,
  },
  {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "Melbourne": 62083,
    "Sydney": 85640,
    "Perth": 42153,
    "Canberra": 74257,
    },
  {
    "Country": "USA",
    "New York": 415910,
    "Miami": 828669,
    "Frankfort": 362642,
    "Portland": 601943,
    "Topeka": 1804762,
  },

];

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Country"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Country; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

  var Country = svg.selectAll(".Country")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Country) + ",0)"; });

  Country.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to consider data[] all indexes present in data array as below:

```
data.forEach(function(d,i) {
            var y0 = 0;
            d.ages = d3.keys(data[i]).filter(function(key) { return  !key.match(/Country/); }).map(function(name) {
                 return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; 
            });
```

Here is the workig bin : https://jsbin.com/qopazukahi/edit?html,output

Answer (score -1):

its difficult to configure d3.js stacked graph.
there is a library over d3.js known as c3.js which is an easy tool to build stacked graph.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', -30, 200, 200, 400, -150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, -100, 200, -150, 50],
            ['data3', -230, 200, 200, -300, 250, 250]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2']
        ]
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [{value:0}]
        }
    }
});
```

here is the example for it.

if you want to rotate the axis use

```
axis: {
        rotated: true
    }
```

which make the axis rotate

for more details refer http://c3js.org/

Comment: I don't think you got the question. my keys are different all together so I get one bar for India from above data and USA/Aus are missing. I was asking is there any way to tweak the data as so , so that I can see all the stacked bars